# Speech synthesis not working on onload event…?

Tags: javascript, speech-synthesis

```js
var body = document.body;

body.onload = speechInterface('Hello sir i am jarvis');

function speechInterface(msg){
  let talkback = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(msg);
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(talkback);
}
```

Comment: It works in the post when converted into a code snippet. More debugging information required?

Comment: When and where the script posted is executed may provide some clues.